# How to make a loop to extract text from hyperlinks in a webpage

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm still quite new to python and trying to use it for webscraping.

Specifically, I want to get all the quotes on [this page](http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm), that are given here: "XXX full quotes by YYY" or in the case there's only one quote: "the full quote by YYY". After getting the text on each page, I want to have them saved as a separate text file.

I've been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI&t=567s), but I'm a little confused in terms of how to filter the html? Honestly, I have barely any experience with HTML so it's a little hard to navigate what it means, but I THINK, the section of interest is this:

```
 <a href="javascript:pop('../2020/
```

Here's my code so far, to open the webpage.

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import Request,urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

import re
#define url of interest
my_url = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'

# set up known browser user agent for the request to bypass HTMLError
req=Request(my_url,headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

#opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(req)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html is jumbled at the moment, so call html using soup function

soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
```

Any help is very appreciated.

**EDIT**:

My idea is that, I'll compile the relevant URLs first and store them, then try and get bs to store the text in each URL. 
I have managed to isolate all the links of interest:

```
tags = soup.findAll("a" , href=re.compile("javascript:pop"))
print(tags)

for links in tags:
    link = links.get('href')
    if "java" in link: 
        print("http://archive.ontheissues.org" + link[18:len(link)-3])
```

Now, how can I extract the text from each of the individual links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `request` and `regular expression` to search particular text and save the text value into `textfile`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
URL = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' }
page=requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
file1 = open("Quotefile.txt","w")
for a in soup.find_all('a',text=re.compile("the full quote by|full quotes by")):
    file1.writelines(a.text.strip() +"\n")
    # print(a.text.strip())
file1.close()
```

**EDITED:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
URL = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' }
page=requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
file1 = open("Quotefile.txt","w")
for a in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile("javascript:pop")):
    shref=a['href'].split("'")[1]

    if ('Background_Free_Trade.htm' not in shref):
        link="http://archive.ontheissues.org" + shref[2:len(shref)]
        print(link)

        file1.writelines(a.text.strip() +"\n")

file1.close()
```

**EDITED2**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
URL = 'http://archive.ontheissues.org/Free_Trade.htm'
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36' }
page=requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
file1 = open("Quotefile.txt","w")
for a in soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile("javascript:pop")):
    shref=a['href'].split("'")[1]
    if ('Background_Free_Trade.htm' not in shref):
        link="http://archive.ontheissues.org" + shref[2:len(shref)]
        print(link)
        pagex=requests.get(link,headers=headers)
        soup=BeautifulSoup(pagex.content,'html.parser')
        print(soup.find('h1').text)

        file1.writelines(soup.find('h1').text +"\n")

file1.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't clear. What I want is actually is the text you see when you click those URLs. I think I have the right idea, but was wondering if you could help me out. I have edited my original comment

Comment: Thanks, I think i JUST got that part too as you posted it (in my new edited comment). So from here, how would I now extract all the text from each of those links and save them in a .txt file?
Also, it seems in your edit that it's leaving out the last character of the URL, it cuts off the "htm" at "ht"

Comment: Well You can do the same request each link and get the relevant text which want.

Comment: I'm not clear on the syntax for getting the entire text on each of the links, and then saving it in a separate file.

Comment: see edited 2 section.I have just taken header of each page.You can find any text you want

Comment: Thanks, I think I can figure it out from here!

Comment: I have up-voted it, but my reputation is too low to show that it has changed. Also, just one question, what does "headers=headers" do in the requests.get(link, headers = headers)? How would I change it to get text, unordered lists, and paragraphs?

Comment: it is HTTP headers to a request.The headers will be overridden by proxy credentials provided in the URL.

Comment: I want to extract the entire body of text, excluding links/<a> tags, instead of just headers, but can't find the syntax

Comment: Suggest you to raise another question and explain what you are after on the post.

Comment: in other words: instead of headers, how to get ALL the text on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Is it something you want

```
soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    for tag in soup.find_all('a'): # type: Tag
        if ('href' in tag.attrs and tag.attrs.get('href').startswith("javascript:pop('../2020/")):
            print(tag)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 34293: invalid start byte

Comment: To be specific,  I want python to open each of those hyperlinks and save the text in them in a separate file.